# Html5 video tag: mp4 video not supported on iOS

Tags: ios, html, video

I have an intro video on this website: http://staging.optiekcardoen.be/. The video on top is playing automatically on most browsers, that's the behaviour I want. On Safari iOS, there's just a play button above the poster image of this video. When I click it, nothing happens... :(

When I integrate the bigbugbunny video from w3schools (https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video) with an absolute path, it works just fine! When I download that same bunny video, upload it to my server and make a relative link in my video-tag, it doesn't work either.

First, I moved the video up with a greather z-index. The problem stayed. Then, I checked with my hosting provider to chang the php version to a more recent one then my xampp php version. Then I asked the producer of my intro video if he wanted to minimize the video, but that didn't fixed anything.

I'm out of possibilities I'm affraid. Is there anyone with another possible answer please?

Comment: have you checked that the encoding (codec, audio etc) of the video is okay?

Comment: I asked the video maker to ensure the video is saved with these settings: "If it is H.264 video, it should meet: up to 1080p, 30 frames per second, High Profile level 4.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;". The video has no audio track, so that's not realy important in this case. Are those settings the encoding settings, or is this someting else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a HTTP vs HTTPS same origin security problem.

If you go to the site in Safari and look at the console you will see:

> Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://staging.optiekcardoen.be".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.

See more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

**Update**:

As Sam mentions in the comment, while the issue above should be addressed, even if this issue is bypassed, the main video, which is not from YouTube, does not play. The main page video has the wrong mime type also - see below:

```html
<source src="/files/intro-320x176-laag.mp4" type="video/webm">
```

**Update 2**

I did a quick test and verified that on Safari at least, an mp4 video will not play if the Mime type is set to webm.

If you set your mime type to mp4 I suspect your video will play properly - i.e. change the end of the line above to:

```html
<source src="/files/intro-320x176-laag.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Comment: The strange things is that the intro video isn't a YouTube video. When you navigate to 'Beestige referenties', there you got 6 Youtube vids. Those vids are playing correctly when you click the play buttons in Safari iOS. So in fact I should change the website to https://staging.optiekcardoen.be insteds of http://staging.optiekcardoen.be?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can turn of the same origin check in safari developer tools and your video still does not play. It definitely does play in Chrome. One possible issue is that you have the wrong mime type at the end of the video - you have webm instead of mp4. It may be that Safari is more sensitive to this than chrome. Can you change this and try again?

Comment: Thank you Mick! I asked my hosting to change the http environment to https. I'm curious ;)

Comment: Big facepalm! Indeed, the mime type in the mp4-line was lazily copied from the webm video. So update 2 did the trick, Mick! Thank you very much for your help!!! (PS: I've changed the domain also to https now, it's better like that ;))

Answer (score 0):

```
<video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" poster="/files/intro.jpg">        
    <p>Uw browser video tag.</p>
</video>
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: <video autoplay="" muted="" loop="" poster="/files/intro.jpg">
        <!--<source src="/files/intro.mp4" type="video/webm">-->
        <!--<source src="/files/polina.mp4" type="video/webm">-->
        <!--<source src="/files/intro-320x176.mp4" type="video/webm">-->
        <source src="/files/intro-320x176-laag.mp4" type="video/webm">
        <!--<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">-->
        <!--<source src="/files/konijn.mp4" type="video/webm">-->
        <p>Uw browser ondersteunt geen video tag.</p>
    </video>

Comment: Hi Kaki, I changed the video attributes. Still no improvement. Bizarre!